# Scaling down a UIButton's background image when using initWithFrame:

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage, contentmode

This is the first time I have ever designed an iOS app so I want to make sure I understand this behavior correctly.

I designed a custom bar button icon for a navigation bar in Photoshop. The final image that I saved in Photoshop was 102 x 45, and yes I realize that these dimensions are bigger than the recommended 44x44 in the iOS 7 design guidelines.

Anyways, I placed my image into the asset folder, and then programmatically set the bar button item with the following code:

```
UIImage* firstButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loginbutton1"];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 102, 45);

    UIButton * someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [someButton setBackgroundImage:firstButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapLoginButton:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];

    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightBarButton;
```

As you can see I set the frame's width and height to the exact size of the image. When I first ran the app, I didn't like the image and thought it was too big. So I changed the width and height parameters in this statement:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 30);
```

And now the image looks perfect on the iPhone screen. This is on an iPhone 4s.

So my main question is, what is actually happening when I change the frame size? Since the frame is now smaller than the actual image size, does the image just get scaled down automatically to fit inside the frame?

Comment: I hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the image get scaled because you are using `backgroundImage` (not `Image`). Both images have different behaviors.

Check the **Xcode Interface Builder**, you can see there, that you can set two images: Image and Background. Background is the `UIImage` that get scaled for the whole frame of the `UIButton`.

[image]

The [UIButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) allows you to access the `imageView` of the `image` (not the`imageView` of the `backgroundImage`)

Because you have access to the `imageView`, you can change the mode of the image with:

```
[[someButton imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeBottomLeft];
```

In [UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewContentMode) you can check all the `UIViewContentModes` provided by Apple.

You can check that changing a little bit your code:

```
[someButton setImage:firstButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[someButton imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeBottomRight];
```